# Django on EC2 security group fo postgresql on RDS

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

edited the DATABASES entry in my settings.py to be:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'Limbo',
        'USER': '<username>',
        'PASSWORD': '<password>',
        'HOST': '<dbname>.<gibberish>.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

now when I `.manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:800`, it says:

> Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

then after a minute or two:

> File
>   "/home/ec2-user///local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 164, in connect
>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async) django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to
>   server: Connection timed out
>           Is the server running on host "..us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.rest.of.ip) and
>   accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I have made sure to include the access via 5432 incoming from my ec2's IP (verified with `curl ifconfig.co`) and the ip listed in the error message (starting with 172 above).  perhaps I need to use a larger subnet (than 32)in the 172 source?

EDIT:  same error when I run `python limbo/manage.py migrate`
EDIT2:  if I allow 5432 connections from any IP in the security group it works, but as stated above, I am allowing my EC2's IP (according to `curl ifconfig.co`'s return value.  what other IP should I be including?

Answer (score 2):

enter the following into the linux command line:
`cd /path/to/djangoproj`
`screen`
`source <env>/bin/activate`

then you should see the command line tool reads something like:
`(<env>)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-243 djangoproj]$`

see that section in the middle: `ip-172-31-26-243`, that's the local ip, use that in the security group settings.  in this case, I used 172.31.26.243/32 as the incoming IP allowed

then try to `runserver` again